# NIC card and network adapters?

Tags: nic

Hopefully I get answer to this question, not sure if this is the correct forum here.

I want to know do laptops (for example, dell, hp etc.) have ONLY ONE NIC card? If so, then how using this card are we able to connect to LAN cable, we are able to connect to WI-FI.

When I see the network adapters, there are many? So what is the relationship  between NIC and these adapters?

Can anyone please help me understand this?

Comment: Please let know me which is the appropriate forum if you intend to close this question :-)

Answer (score 1):

There is a NIC for each type (Cable, WiFi and Blutooth ...).

For example: In a PC, which normally comes with one NIC for cable only, you can buy a Wifi NIC to make it connect to WiFi networks.